# Mailchimp: Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js”

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailchimp

I'm using a Mailchimp embedded form. However, It seems that the Mailchimp library `/mc-validate.js` is not being loaded into the page. Based on other articles I'm checking to see if there are other `<script>` tags that might be conflicting but I can't find any others. The other script tag is the one I'm using to load Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I still get the error in the console:
[image]

The error comes from the following line of code which is the script tag loading the Mailchimp library:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='ADDRESS';ftypes[3]='address';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';fnames[5]='BIRTHDAY';ftypes[5]='birthday';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding the https:// to the src? src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/..."

Comment: How are you checking the web page? In what environment is it currently running?

Comment: @KostasX adding `https` fixes one of the errors however I'm still getting `T file://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I'm checking in Google Chrome, mostly is a static HTML page

Comment: Maybe you should search to see where this is coming from, and add the https there also. Are you trying this on a local web page that you just double clicked?

Comment: You should try using a local web server.

Comment: yes i'm running it locally

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting that reference as a local file. Changing both to https:// addressed the issue for me.